# How to make a 555/556-based one-shot timer on a breadboard?

Tags: circuit-design, 555, homework, breadboard

How can I implement the circuit as described below on a breadboard?

The Monostable or “One Shot”

1. Refer to the datasheet for the NE555 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf Find and read the configuration information for
   the monostable circuit.
2. Using your breadboard and the relevant components, configure your 555/556 to operate
   as a one shot that provides an output pulse approximately 1 second long. Connect a
   pushbutton switch with a 10K pullup resistor to provide the trigger input. If you have no
   pushbutton, just connect a 10K pullup to the trigger input, and then use a jumper wire to
   momentarily ground the input when you want to reset the timer. Connect an LED with an
   appropriate current limiting resistor to the output of the 555 so you can see when the
   output changes state.
3. Connect the circuit to a 5 volt DC power supply and verify the operation of the circuit using
   the oscilloscope.
4. Modify the circuit to create a pulse around 10 seconds in duration. Verify the operation of
   the circuit by observing the period of illumination or dark) of your LED when the circuit is
   triggered

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... what is the difficulty that you face? ... all that can be said right now is "follow the directions step by step"

Comment: You have the instructions already. What is the question really? If you are stuck, explain where are you stuck, and what you need to continue.

Comment: How can build the breadbord circuit for this question

Comment: Do you have a breadboard and suitable wires and the 555 chip with you ? First step is to plug the IC into the bread board and connect the supply and return wires. Are you able to do that ? If so, please post a photo of what you have already done.

Comment: This [page](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/555-timer-monostable-circuit.php) most likely has the answers you are looking for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet includes a complete circuit diagram for a monostable (oneshot) circuit.

[image]

Directly underneath the schematic is a section that describes how to calculate the length of the output pulse:

[image]

The value for \$R_A\$ is in ohms.  Use farads for the value of \$C\$.  The value of \$t_W\$ is in seconds.

You are given a requirement of 10 seconds - that's \$t_W\$.  Pick a resistor from the ones you have and calculate a capacitor value.  Alternatively, pick a capacitor from the ones you have and calculate the resistor value.

Take note of the required values, then assemble the circuit by plugging parts and wires into your breadboard.

If you aren't familiar with breadboards, take a look at a breadboard tutorial.

[This one from SparkFun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard/all) goes into some detail about how breadboards are constructed and used. It helps to know how they are constructed when you try to use one.  There's a lot of advertisements on that page - just scroll down past them to get to the interesting parts.